# Перенос строки в атрибуте title

Tags: html, firefox

Как сделать перенос строки в атрибуте title в firefox?
В опере работает такое `<img title='первая строка\nвторая строка\nи тд.'>`. Отображает так:

```
первая строка

вторая строка

и тд.
```

А вот *firefox* всё лепит в одну строку:(

Comment: извините, я чтот не о том подумал))вполне, возможно, что никак. но есть такая замечательная штука, как Tooltip. можно попробовать с помощью этой техники решить Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В title передавать знак переноса строки = полное отсутствие кросбраузерности. Рекомендую использовать Tooltip. Если нужны  подробности смотрите на [этом сайте](http://seo-schemer.ru/ru/registration/). Здесь при наведении на информационный значок. JS файл на этой же странице, СSS там же.

Answer (score 2):

1 Вариант:
 
`<img title='первая строка
вторая строка
и тд.' />`

2 Вариант:
 
`<img title='первая строка&#013;вторая строка&#013;и тд.' />`

Comment: Согласно стандарту HTML любое количество подряд идущих пробельных символов должно интерпретироваться как один пробел.